# "could not start ksmserver. check your installation" kubuntu 16.10 x86

Tags: linux

Inicie mi kubuntu en forma live para comprobar compatibilidad y funciono perfectamente

Después De Una instalación me aparece la interfaz de inicio y cuando se va a cargar el escritorio me presenta una ventana emergente mostrando ese fallo

Answer (score 1):

"could not start ksmserver. check your installation" kubuntu 16

Lo solucione cuando me presentaba el error abri consola con la combinación de teclas ctrl+alt+F1 y me apareció consola conecte la pc por cable y posterior a ello la actualice con apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade && shutdown -r now

El comando sirve para actualizar la lista de últimos programas posibles a descargar y actualizar, después actualizo y después lo reinicia

Otra opción es instalar gdm apt-get -y install gdm3